# How can I fill the first column of a DataTable?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, datacolumn

I fill the first column of a DataTable using SqlDataAdapter and then display it correctly inside a  DataGridView.

```
foreach(string oras in IdList)
{
    using(SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT Localitate FROM Orase WHERE IdLocalitate = @id", con))
    {
        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", oras);
        sda.Fill(tabel);
    }
}
```

[Screenshot of the DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rEyC.png)

But after that I want to fill the DataGridView with 4 more columns, using similar code:

```
using(SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT Frecventa, DataStart, DataStop, Ziua FROM Planificari", con))
{
    sda.Fill(tabel);
    tabelDate.DataSource = tabel;
}
```

Now my DataGridView displays those 4 columns at the end of the first one, which is not what i want.

[Screenshot of the DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx9tV.png)

How do I make the last 4 columns display in line with the first one?

Comment: Why is the 1st row of the 1st select matched to the 1st row of the second?  Its all effectively random atm as there is no order.  Usually if the data is related there is a way to express that relationship in a single query that returns all the data.

Comment: It is related because I know the way they are ordered and it matches.

Comment: Without an ORDER BY the order is not guaranteed, the fact it looks ok should be considered a fluke.

Comment: If you know how data is matched, then you should write a single query, joining 2 tables, and fill DataGrid in single run

Comment: You may need to take control of creating the columns instead of letting the DGV autocreate them. But, as has been noted the whole idea of patching data together instead of joining them is a mistake..

Comment: What is the relationship between Orase and Planificary data?   How is one matched against the other?  Once you have that you can join the tables to get all the results in one go and then adding them to the table should be a single step